# GoogleMaps-Partial stops working in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-3, angularjs-directive, partials, angularjs-routing

I am working on a web project with AngularJS + Foundation 5, and I am actually having some troubles with the partial views. There is no problem when I write everything in the same index.html page, but the components stop working when I try to make everything a little bit more "dynamic" by saving components as partials, and then linking them in the index.html. I had the same problem with Foundation 5 + AngularJS at the beginning, but I solved it in some situations by calling foundation in the compile function of the controller.

index.html: I tried it with the following 2 methods:

```
<ng-include src="partials/google-maps.html"></ng-include>

<div data-ng-controller="googleMapsCtrl">
    <div google-maps></div>
</div>
```

The Controller:

```
app.controller('googleMapsCtrl', [])
.directive('google-maps', ['$compile',
function () {
    return {
        templateUrl: './partials/google-maps.html',
        compile: function () {
            jQuery(document).foundation();
        }
    }; }]);
```

And the map.css, which is included in the index.html:

```
.angular-google-map-container { height: 400px; }
```

I think I am making something wrong when I include the partials. Some idea how to solve this problem?

Thank you very much!